# Problem with UIPopOverController shrinking in width when navigationController pushes a new view(screenshots included)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, width, uipopovercontroller

Ok I have a view that we will call homeView. When a certain button is pushed on homeView, a UIPopOverController is presented in the following way:

```
self.studyPicker = [[[StudyPickerController alloc] initWithStudyArray:self.studyArray ViewNum:butto.tag] autorelease];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:self.studyPicker];

    _studyPicker.delegate = self;
    self.studyPickerPopover = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController] autorelease];               

    [self.studyPickerPopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(955,60, 22,10) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Which works great. I get a nice big popover controller that displays my tableView data just the way I need it. Just as an FYI, in my StudyPickerController viewDidLoad method, I am also setting this:

```
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(1000.0, 610.0);
```

Which allows me to make the size of my tableView nice and big. **The problem I am experiencing** is after I select a row in this first tableView. The navigationController pushes the new view just fine, but then the width of my popover controller gets cut in half! It doesn't make any sense! I have tried everything and can't figure out what is going on. In the new view, called ScreenView, it also has the same code in viewDidLoad:

```
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(1000.0, 610.0);
```

**An interesting observation** that I've made but don't know what to do with is that if I take out the contentForSize code from the **Second** view in the tableView, or the one that I am trying to push to within the controller, when it pushes, it gets cut in half again, to the width of a standard popover controller you see in like Safari. But adding that code in makes it 2 times as wide, like there are two glued together or something, but it is still more narrow than the original width.

I don't know what's going on here, hopefully someone can help me out!

Thanks

Here is an image of the width it should stay:
[image]

And then here it is after it pushes the new view:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

For each view you are presenting in the `UIPopoverController`, set the property 
`contentSizeForViewInPopover`

For example:

`myViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSize(120.0f, 320.0f);`

You will need to account for the size of the `UINavigationBar` (that you get from the `UINavigationBar`) inside the `UIPopoverController` but overall that controls the stretching and contracting of the `UIPopoverController`.